# pass vue js component parameter to vuex method-style getter parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex, getter

New to vuex. Simple pokemon SPA that should display pokemon by generation and type. I am trying to write a method-style getter that will pass a component's parameter. EDIT: moved currentType to state:

```
//Vuex.Store
state: {
    pokemon: [],
    currentType: 'all'
},
getters:{
   availablePokemon: (state) => (currentType) => {
      if(!currentType || currentType === 'all'){
        return state.pokemon
      }else{
        return state.pokemon.filter(pokemon => {
//some api objects have two types
          if(pokemon.types.length === 2){
            if(pokemon.types[0] == currentType || pokemon.types[1] == currentType){
              return true
            }
          }else if(pokemon.types[0] == currentType){
            return true
          }
        })
      }
},
mutations:{
    changeType(state, type){
      state.currentType = type
    }
},
actions:{
   updateType(context, type){
      context.commit('changeType', type)
    }}
}
```

EDIT:

```
//Pokemon.vue
       <select name="type" id="type" @change="updateType($event.target.value)">
          <option v-for="(type, index) in types"
                  :key="index" 
                  :value="type">{{ type }}</option>
        </select>

       <li v-for="(pokemon, index) in allPokemon"
            :key="index">
            {{ pokemon.name }}
        </li>

export default {
  data(){
    return{
      types: ['all', 'bug', 'dragon'],
    }
  },

  computed: {
    allPokemon(){
//this fails, says currentType is undefined
      return this.$store.getters.availablePokemon(currentType)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateType(type){
      this.$store.dispatch('updateType', type)
    }
  }
```

The component method-style getter doesn't recognize the parameter. I've tried moving the currentType to my store (and updating it with an action => mutation => etc), but that didn't work either. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Architecturally, I'd store the `currentType` in the 
Vuex state object. Then, you can reference the `currentType` in the getter function - and - also reference the `currentType` app wide.

JSFiddle here for your reference (see javascript tab and console output): https://jsfiddle.net/qb47x2z1/38/

Comment: I've moved currentType to state, added the necessary action => mutation, but in my component vue if I write: return this.$store.getters.availablePokemon(currentType), it says currentType is undefined, if I don't pass the param no list items render at all

Comment: @notmynamelastname - Can you please post your updated code?

Comment: I've edited the code. Not sure how to pass the param in the method-style getter....

Comment: @notmynamelastname - if you're storing the currentType in the Vuex state, you won't need to pass it in anymore, just set it in the Vuex state before you call the getter. Don't pass anything in to the getter anymore as it should already be available in the Vuex state. See my fiddle above.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Unfortunately the list doesn't re-render. Any ideas?

Comment: @notmynamelastname - definitely check out vue dev tools for chrome - it might point out the issue for you. Especially the Vuex tab: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en